# In IE 10 scripts run only on the first load per tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

In IE 10 scripts run only on the first load per tab. After I reload a page, js doesn't run and I get an only server-side rendered page. Console tab in dev tools is empty. I don't receive any error. That behavior manifested only in IE 10. In IE 11 all ok.

Added core js library. App use gatsby framework

```
console.log('TestPage file'); // that console.log works fine every time
class TestPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('TestPage constructor'); // that console.log works only on first load
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('TestPage  componentDidMount'); // that console.log works only on first load
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{isClient ? 'TestPage  CLIENT' : 'TestPage  SERVER'}</div>;
  }
}
```

isClient is true on a client-side

I expected that js run every time

Comment: Are you loading the polyfills some older browsers require? (See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#browser-support)).

Comment: Yes. If I wouldn't do it the first load didn't work well

Comment: if you've already included polyfills, where did you include them in gatsby's structure?

Comment: in gatsby-browser.js file

Answer (score 1):

React is not compatible right away with all versions of IE,

From the official documentation :

React supports all popular browsers, including Internet Explorer 9 and above, although some polyfills are required for older browsers such as IE 9 and IE 10.

> We don’t support older browsers that don’t support ES5 methods, but
>   you may find that your apps do work in older browsers if polyfills
>   such as es5-shim and es5-sham are included in the page. You’re on your
>   own if you choose to take this path.

---

To make your application work on IE (11 or 9) you will have to install React-app-polyfill :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill

Features :

Each polyfill ensures the following language features are present:

```
Promise (for async / await support)
window.fetch (a Promise-based way to make web requests in the browser)
Object.assign (a helper required for Object Spread, i.e. { ...a, ...b })
Symbol (a built-in object used by for...of syntax and friends)
Array.from (a built-in static method used by array spread, i.e. [...arr])
```

Usage

First, install the package using Yarn or npm:

```
npm install react-app-polyfill
```

Now, you can import the entry point for the minimal version you intend to support. For example, if you import the IE9 entry point, this will include IE10 and IE11 support.

Internet Explorer 9

```
// This must be the first line in src/index.js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';

// ...
```

Internet Explorer 11

```
// This must be the first line in src/index.js
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';

// ...
```

---

You can also configure your manifest to handle different browsers, using the following doc : https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist

example :

```
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "ie >= 9"
]
```

Comment: Ty for a response, but I already have polyfills in my code. In first time page load correctly. Problems start when I reload a page